# R6 array member, copy on update

Tags: r, matrix, copy, insert-update, r6

the following code

```
require(R6)
Array <- R6Class(
  "Array",
  public=list(
    x=matrix(0,0,0),
    initialize=function(a,b,c){
      self$x <- matrix(a,b,c)
    },
    assign=function(z){
      self$x[1,1] <- z
      invisible(self)
    }
  )
)
x <- Array$new(0,10,10)
tracemem(x$x)
x$assign(1)
y <- matrix(0,10,10)
tracemem(y)
y[1,1] <- 1
```

yields this output

```
> [1] "<0x55ae7be40040>"
> tracemem[0x55ae7be40040 -> 0x55ae7b403700]: <Anonymous> 
> > [1] "<0x55ae7b254c90>"
> >
```

which implies that when the R6 member array is updated a copy of the array is made, whereas when the plain array is updated, the element is update "in-place" (i.e. no copy is generated).

Any idea how I can achieve this for the R6 object?

Comment: AFAIR the fact that no copy is made for the direct assignment is an optimisation in the R interpreter VM that relies on heuristics to figure out that the object can be safely modified in-place, and it is *very* conservative in its estimates (and thus performs unnecessary copies as in the case you’ve found). There’s probably nothing from within R that we can do to change that, the change would have to happen in the source code of the R VM itself.

Comment: Also, are you testing this in RStudio? Or are you using the R executable directly? Some times using RStudio creates extra copies because it displays information in the Environment Browser. At least that used to be very common. Haven't tested in the latest versions of the IDE

Comment: @MrFlick that is fascinating - I'm finding the same issue in VScode. If I run this as an attached R session (which has a similar environment browser to RStudio) then even `y` is copied on modify. But if I just run it in a terminal (even within VScode) it is not. I had no idea - I'm wondering if this ever makes a practical difference to the code I'm running. A quick check suggests it doesn't seem to affect `data.table`, which I generally use with datasets that take a noticeable amount of time to copy, so I'm hoping not...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the semantics for subset assignment in R. Subset assignment is the `$<-` operator (as in  `x$y <- 1`) or the `[<-` operator (as in `x[y] <- 1`).

In R, when you do something like `self$x <- y`, that actually gets turned into something like this:

```
`*tmp*` <- x
x <- "$<-"(`*tmp*`, y)
rm(`*tmp*`)
```

This creates `*tmp*`, which initially points to the same object in memory as `x`. However, when the assignment to `x` happens in the second line, R makes a copy of the object and modifies it. This copy of the object needs to be GC'd (garbage collected) later, and that takes time.

See here for more info about subset assignment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment

(Note that in some cases, R knows that there is only a single reference to the object, and when that happens, it will modify the object in place. That is what happens with `y` in your example above, but not with `x`.)

One way to avoid this extra copying is to use the `<<-` operator instead. First, here's a demonstration of using it without R6 to show the speed difference:

```
local({
  self <- environment()
  x <- 0
  y <- 0
  bench::mark(
    self$x <- x+1,
    y <<- y+1,
    iterations = 1e5
  )
})
#> # A tibble: 2 × 13
#>   expression        min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`  n_itr  n_gc total_time
#>   <bch:expr>      <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>  <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#> 1 self$x <- x + 1 246ns  369ns  2405536.        0B     96.2  99996     4    41.57ms
#> 2 y <<- y + 1         0   41ns 16327450.        0B      0   100000     0     6.12ms
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

For the `self$x <- x+1` case, notice the number of GC events, 4. And for the `y <<- y+1` case, there are 0 GC events, and each iteration is about 9x faster on average.

The reason `<<-` is so much faster here is because, when you do `y <<- y+1`, it replaces `y` directly in place, without making a copy.

---

In order to use `<<-` with an R6 object, you need to set `portable=FALSE`. Here's a modified version:

```
require(R6)
Array <- R6Class(
  "Array",
  portable=FALSE,
  public=list(
    x = matrix(0,0,0),
    initialize=function(a,b,c){
      x <<- matrix(a,b,c)
    },
    assign=function(z){
      x[1,1] <<- z
      invisible(self)
    }
  )
)
x <- Array$new(0,10,10)
tracemem(x$x)
x$assign(1)
y <- matrix(0,10,10)
tracemem(y)
y[1,1] <- 1
```

When I run it, the `x$assign(1)` does **not** cause a tracemem message to be printed, which is the same as `y$assign(1)`.

This will improve performance, but note that `portable=FALSE` will cause problems if you try to use inheritance with this class across packages. (https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Portable.html)

See my comments on this GitHub issue for a little more detail: https://github.com/r-lib/R6/issues/201#issuecomment-583486168

Comment: You write “R makes a copy of the object and modifies it” which is confusing because it doesn’t apply here: `self` (= the object) is a *reference object*, and this is the one exception in R where no object copy happens upon assignment. At most what happens is that R copies the *name* (`self`) into the current scope, but referring to the original object (as confirmed by e.g. `lobstr::obj_addr(self)` before and after assignment).